# I can't get my code to break out of the switch statement

Tags: c

I can't get my delete record function to break out of the switch case or even give me an error when the record doesn't exist. Could someone please tell me why this is?

Any help is much appreciated!

I can't get my delete record function to break out of the switch case or even give me an error when the record doesn't exist. Could someone please tell me why this is?

Any help is much appreciated!

```
void delete_record();
void displayContent();

struct Update
{
    char studentName[50];
    char studentID [50];
    char emailID[100];
    char courseID[5];
    char grade[50];

} update2;

int main ()
{
  int num;
  
  do
  {
  
  printf("1. Delete a record for the specific name\n");
  printf("2. Display Content of File\n");
  printf("6. Exit\n");



  switch(num)
  {
    
    case 1:
    printf("this is a test\n");
    delete_record();
    break;
    //displayContent();
    //printf("this is a test 2\n");

    case 2:
    printf("\n\nDiplaying Contents of File\n\n");
    displayContent();

    default:
    printf("Give me a break!\n");
    break;
  }

  scanf("%d", &num);
   } while (num != 6);
    return 0;



}

void delete_record()
{
   
   FILE *fp;
   FILE *fp_tmp;
   fp = fopen ("BINARY_FILE.txt", "w");
  
   char studentsID[20];
   printf("enter studentID to delete:");
   scanf("%s",studentsID);
  
  printf("is this a test?\n");
  
   while(fread(&update2,sizeof(update2),1,fp))
   {
      printf("this is another test\n");
       if(strcmp(update2.studentID,studentsID) != 0)
       {
           //printf("testing\n");
           fwrite(&update2,sizeof(update2),1,fp);
       }
       else
       {
        printf("No student with that student ID\n");
       }
   }
   printf("more tests\n");
   fclose(fp);

   return;
}

void displayContent()
{
  char c;
  // Open file
    FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen ("BINARY_FILE.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File Has No Content\n");
        exit(0);
    }
  
    // Read contents from file
    
    c = fgetc(fp);
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        printf ("%c", c);
        c = fgetc(fp);
    }
  
    fclose(fp);
    //return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Copy/pasting repetitive text to bypass the minimum length requirements is not appropriate. Not only is it a violation of the site guidelines, it is also disrespectful to the users you're asking for help. If it's not worth your effort to explain the problem, why should it be worth ours to help you? Please spend some time reading [ask], and then [edit] your post .

Answer (score 0):

When using scanf to read from the keyboard you must remember
that *all* characters that you enter are written to the in-buffer,
this means that if you type in

42<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

The <kbd>ENTER</kbd> will also be present in the in-buffer, so next time you call `scanf` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> will still be in the buffer and then scanf returns 0 since the format specificier "%d" doesn't match.

The easiest way to handle input from keyboard in C and to avoid the hassle of `scanf` in-buffer by using `fgets()` to read from the keyboard, then use `sscanf()` to cherry pick from the buffer:

```
// always check return value from all runtime functions when possible
char buffer[128];
if (fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL)
{
  if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", &num) == 1)
  {
    
  }
  else {...}
}
else {...}
```